# Get list of all users with Checkin permissions in TFS

Tags: c#, version-control, tfs

I am trying to programattically find all users with Checkin privileges for each Project in a TFS Project Collection. Previously, i was able to fetch all Project Admins in a TFS collection using the below code

```
 var teamProject = teamProjects[i];
                var security = new Security();
                var myTeamProj = new TeamProject();
                myTeamProj.Name = teamProject.Name;
                myTeamProj.TeamProjectCollectionName = teamProject.TeamProjectCollection.Name;
                security.TeamProject = myTeamProj;
                var groupMemberships = new List<GroupMembership>();
                Identity[] appGroups =
                  sec.ListApplicationGroups(teamProject.ArtifactUri.AbsoluteUri);

                foreach (Identity group in appGroups)
                {
                    if (group.DisplayName.ToString() != "Project Administrators")
                    continue;
.....
```

Can I extend this to query permissions which are project specific? else, what is the best method to fetch list of users with 'Checkin' rights